# ansible git autodeploy by webhooks

Tags: deployment, git, github, ansible-playbook

How to automate deployment from git repository hosted on github / bitbucket to ubuntu server using ansible?

In github repostory settings->webhooks i can add webhook for pull to master, that will call my server
[image: webhooks]

I have self-made solution, written in node.js, that pulls from git and restarts service, but want to migrate to ansible

I'm new to ansible, but know little about [ansible-playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html)

There is github webhook module for ansible https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/github_hooks_module.html

But i dont understand, what .yml file i need to write

Also i need to pass secret API keys using enviroment variables. How to store it in keyring?

### How to help

Write .yml file for ansible-playbook, that service web server for hook with secret field and `git pull` plus run git hooks like `npm i`, that specified in repo(from unprivileged user) and say, how to use it

Say, can i use github webhook module with bitbucket?

Comment: Hmm. You could send a webhook to Ansible Tower/AWX, i think.

Answer (score 0):

The `github_hooks` module is deprecated and used from Ansible to create Hooks on Github. What you want is a hook-call that is thrown, when f.e. a Git push was done (so the other way around).

Github needs a HTTP service to call, when you want that Ansible starts doing something. Ansible itself cannot do it, because it isn't a server and it doesn't listen to anything. Its just a "script".

You have two options:
Put all you Ansible scripts etc. into AWX/Ansible Tower. That is a Webservice, that has a REST-API. Please have a look into https://keithtenzer.com/2019/06/24/ci-cd-with-ansible-tower-and-github/ for a good description.

If you don't want to install AWX. Install somekind of HTTP server on the ansible control machine and write a script (like the one you already did) that starts the Ansible-Playbook, when Github is calling it.